# How would I execute a query for best performance with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

How would I execute a query for best performance with PyMYSQL, since it's an external connection (between *Denmark* and *Germany*) there could be "code-blocking"s?

Isn't there a method called threading or something like that?

**Basic query:**

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT names ,ages FROM id")
```

So to summerize: What is the best way of doing this?

If it's not possible with PyMYSQL, you're more than welcome to link other libaries where it's do-able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [aiopg](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html) if you are using postgreSQL supports Sqlalchemy also.

Uses [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html) internally to make it async.
No need to go for threading.

If you are using other than postgreSQL try using Asyncio with Sqlalchmey.

Comment: I'm not really excited about stepping away from MySQL

Comment: Try sqlalchemy with asyncio. Sqlachemy supports mysql.